# How to return to the last fragment after pressing home button or exit the android app?

Tags: java, android, navigation, fragment, fragment-backstack

when returning to the app after pressing home button or exit the app it returns to the first fragment of the app (splash screen) I need it to return to the last fragment before pressing home button, if I were on the home fragment and pressed the home button when returning I need to open on the home fragment not the splash screen fragment.

I am using navigation component, but I cannot handle this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Shared Preference or Data Store.